# UI freezed on self.tableView beginUpdates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My UI and UItableview scroll get freezed when i want to insert new row

inside my table.

the program gets new rows in end of first 10 like this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
      {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];


 NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger currentCount = self.entries.count;
 for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < p.appRecordList.count; i++) {
 [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentCount+i inSection:0]];
                 }
NSArray *temp_1 =[self.entries arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:p.appRecordList];
self.entries = temp_1;
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
                   [self.tableView endUpdates];

          });
 });
```

also im using custome cell height for my program like this :

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSLog(@"heightForRowAtIndexPath called");
        return [self heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
- (CGFloat)heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static UITableViewCell *sizingCell = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell2";
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    });

    [self configureCellXXX:sizingCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:sizingCell];
}

- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell {
    [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
}
```

as i checked out table freeze is equal when to when heightForRowAtIndexPath are getting called. is there any way to avoid this freeze ?
also when i scroll longer and longer the freeze time gets highter depend on row counts.

Comment: have you implemented also estimatedHEightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: no im not using estimatedHEightForRowAtIndexPath for my cell. im subclassing the cell and the row changes after the cell build up iguess

Comment: If you calculate height at runtime you should use it, just pass an average number. In this way the table view will calculate the height only for visible cells